# cPanel newbie: how do I overwrite virtualhost settings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, virtualhost, cpanel

I have a client who wants to be able to add/delete/modify email addresses etc through cPanel, but I'd much rather add my own virtualhosts config for the actual site instead of a cPanel generated one. (A bunch of reasons. Don't want to install cPanel's ruby, would rather use passenger than mongrel, etc etc).

I don't have a whole lot of experience with cPanel, but by the look of things it takes over httpd.conf & auto-generates a virtualhost for the site - and overwrites stuff if I try to make any changes to the virtualhost settings. Is there a simple means to overwrite these settings without removing the rest of the site's functionality from cPanel?

Cheers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in guessing that cPanel takes over a lot of things and auto-generates certain configs. To be honest, I have no idea what it does in regard to virtualhosts configs, but I **do have** recent experience in other areas which tends to confirm your suspicion:

So, to illustrate... cPanel comes stock with Rails 2.3.5. On the cPanel GemSet page, you can see Rails 3.0.6 shows as available, and even lets you install it via cPanel or SSH/BASH. This results in no error message at all (in fact, cPanel itself reports it as installed), but a `rails --version` command at SSH/BASH still shows version 2.3.5. [After some research on on the cPanel forums](http://forums.cpanel.net/f145/case-44197-mod_rails-passenger-instead-mongrel-rails-3-support-152577.html), I discovered that this is because cPanel is **hard coded** for Mongrel support, and Mongrel doesn't support Rails past version 2.3.8. According to one of their moderators, they're looking at a possible Passenger solution, but it's still in the early stages of coding and months away.

So, while I realize my example doesn't specifically answer your question about virtualhosts, I think it confirms the validity of your suspicion that cPanel overrides certain settings, and may even be hard coded in ways that aren't immediately transparent...